# const_cast c++ did not work for me

Tags: c++, casting, constants

trying to understand the usage of const_cast. Code like the following:

```
const char* text="bb";
(const_cast<char&>(*text))='a';
cout<<*text;
```

...generates a runtime error.

Another question, in memory, how does the runtime (it) know that this area is const or not, what kind of flag is this ?

Comment: IMHO - It is a bad idea to use casts - avoid them and only use them if necessary. I have a strong feeling that people that use casts have something wrong in their design.

Answer (score 8):

That code invokes **undefined behaviour**; it is not valid to write to a string literal (nor indeed to any `const` object).

The C++ standard does not define how this should fail (or even that it **must** fail).  But on a typical platform, it will be up to the OS and the underlying hardware to detect the problem.  The storage for `"bb"` will typically be in a dedicated section of the executable, which is marked as read-only.  See e.g. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_protection.

However, there are uses of `const_cast` that don't invoke undefined behaviour.  e.g.:

```
int x = 5;  // Not a const object

const int *p = &x;

int *q = const_cast<int *>(p);

*q = 6;  // This is ok
```

Comment: why you say string const must fail , what is your point here ?

Comment: @Moatz: I mean that there is no guarantee that writing to a string literal will cause a crash or an error message.

Answer (score 0):

The string might be put in static memory. So it is an undefined behaviour. 
Try this

```
char t[]="bb";
const char* text = t;
(const_cast<char&>(*text))='a';
cout<<*text;
```

You can only const_cast something which you know is not really const. In this case, even if text is const, we know that it points to t which is not const. Hence we can safely cast away the const.

Comment: 2- how you get notification from stackoverflow about some c++ related questions ?
3- any advice how to get this book : robert Sedgewick algorithms in c++ part1-4

best ,

Comment: how string put as static ? what is the differenc ebetween t[] and char* ?

Comment: `char[]` is an array. `char*` is a pointer to an char which might be created using `char[]` or `"blah"` or `malloc(n)`

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the run-time *doesn't* know whether a particular variable is actually `const`. If you cast away `const`-ness, you get undefined behavior if you end up writing to a variable defined as const (as opposed to a normal variable to which you happen to have a const pointer/reference).

If they wanted to mandate that the run-time "know" about things being `const`, then they'd probably prescribe specific behavior (e.g., throwing a particular exception) when/if you write to a const variable. Some systems would support that quite easily -- but others wouldn't, so a specific response isn't required.